# Selenium (Java): ordered list of webelements but with nested divs

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am working with JavaSE and Selenium WebDriver within Chrome. My task is to find a set of input fields and do stuff with them. The issue is that I have to do stuff in the presented order they are available on the web page.

So I would find them via XPATH, because that's what works in the given web page. Let's say that I have a set of inputs on the following path: ...`/form/div/div/div`
However for reasons I cannot say, certain type of input fields (such as text and numbers) are in the following path: ...`/form/div/div`

The problem is that one set of the inputs are one div 'deeper' than the others, so when I save them to a `List<WebElement>` with `driver.findElements`, i can't really save their order.

I thought of finding the inputs with `id`, but the id names have a space in it which Selenium apparently dislikes. I am not sure if relative XPATH could be of help in this case.

Your comments are appreciated.

Comment: I can't think of any logical reason to have to do it in layout order, but if getting the elements in an arraylist does not produce the desired output, you'll have to get smaller arraylists or do them one-by-one in whatever order you're required.  Also, there's no reason an xpath would not accept an ID with any number of spaces.  Please show an example of an xpath that you believe is failing for that reason.  A section of HTML code would also be useful, both in your original post.

Comment: @MilanSz. Update the question with your relevant _HTML_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ (if any)

Comment: I had the realization that I should have read more about relative xpath and I asked the wrong question. Basically what I was looking for was the 'and' operand within a relative xpath expression, which is the pipe character. To any other juniors somehow getting here on this page: read about XPATH on W3schools first. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the mistake of not reading enough about XPATH. What I was looking for was the 'and' operand within an xpath expression. If you are a beginner like me, please read about it on w3schools.

Basically the following code solved my issue, as a workaround:

`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@required=''] | //select[@required='']"));`